# Sequel: How to use 'order by' in a view with tinytds

Tags: ruby, sql-server, sql-order-by, sequel, tiny-tds

I need to create a view with an `order by`-clause with sequel, tinytds and MSSQL

When I do so, I get the error

```
TinyTds::Error: The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP or FOR XML is also specified. (Sequel::DatabaseError)
```

My examplecode:

```
require 'sequel'

DB = Sequel.tinytds(
                    :host     =>  'server', 
                    :database=> 'DB',
                )     
#Remove data from previous test
DB.drop_table(:testtab1) if DB.table_exists?(:testtab1)
DB.drop_view(:v_testtab1) rescue Sequel::DatabaseError
DB.drop_view(:v_testtab2) rescue Sequel::DatabaseError

DB.create_table(:testtab1){
  primary_key :id
  field :a, :type => :nvarchar, :size => 10
  field :b, :type => :nvarchar, :size => 10
}

#Here the error comes up
#"SELECT * FROM `testtab1` ORDER BY `b`"
DB.create_view(:v_testtab1, DB[:testtab1].order_by(:b))
```

See [solution on SQL-side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5945851/sql-problem-the-order-by-clause-is-invalid-in-views) is easy. Instead of the

```
SELECT * FROM `testtab1` ORDER BY `b`
```

I need a

```
SELECT top 100 percent * FROM `testtab1` ORDER BY `b`
```

---

I found a solution with an additional obsolete column (without the column `dummy` I get an invalid comma):

```
sel = DB[:testtab1].select(Sequel.lit('top 100 percent "" as dummy'), *DB[:testtab1].columns)
#SELECT top 100 percent "" as dummy, [ID], [A], [B] FROM [TESTTAB1]
DB.create_view(:v_testtab2, sel.order_by(:b))
```

A similar solution can be made with `limit`:

```
#Take a big number to get all entries.
#DB[:testtab1].count would take the number in moment of view creation, not usage.
sel = DB[:testtab1].limit(99999999999) 
#SELECT TOP (99999999999) * FROM [TESTTAB1]
DB.create_view(:v_testtab3, sel.order_by(:b))
```

But I'm looking for a nicer solution. Is there another better possibility?

If it is important:

- Ruby 2.1
- Sequel 4.19
- tiny_tds-0.6.2-x64-mingw32
- MSSQL 10.50.2500.0, 64 bit

Comment: See my answer on **[SQL Server Query Error -ORDER BY clause is invalid in views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36697511/sql-server-query-error-order-by-clause-is-invalid-in-views/61702593#61702593)**.