# How to update bottom two rows of a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have created below query to create a trigger to update the `lastUpdatedTime`. I need to update the bottom two rows using the trigger below.

But when I use

```
ORDER BY p.id DESC;
```

I get an error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'order'

```
CREATE TRIGGER trgAfterUpdate12 
ON [spider3].[ProductClassModulePeriod]
FOR INSERT, UPDATE
AS
    UPDATE TOP(2) p 
    SET [lastUpdatedTime] = GETDATE()
    FROM [spider3].[ProductClassModulePeriod] AS p
    INNER JOIN inserted AS i ON p.id = i.id;
```

Tried using **WITH** but gets below error

```
CREATE TRIGGER trgAfterUpdate122 
ON [spider3].[ProductClassModulePeriod]
FOR INSERT, UPDATE
AS
    WITH q AS
    (
        SELECT * 
        FROM [spider3].[ProductClassModulePeriod] AS p
        INNER JOIN inserted AS i ON p.id = i.id
        ORDER BY p.primaryKey DESC
    )
    UPDATE q 
    SET [lastUpdatedTime] = GETDATE();
```

**Error:**

> The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified.

How can I update the bottom 2 rows?

Comment: where do you put "order by p.id desc" in the query, I don't see it here ?

Comment: @AngelDeykov updated

Comment: "bottom 2" of what? The `inserted` table? The main table?

Comment: A table doesn't have a *bottom* row - you must mean the two rows with the highest / lowest key values - but which?

Comment: @Stu two rows with highest primaryKey

Comment: You can use `row_number` for this purpose, I'm not sure if you can use an updatable CTE in the context of joining to the *inserted* table however, I would need to test it.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/54137832/891715

Answer (score 2):

You can use this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/655031/9870193) and implement it to update for top 2 rows after sorting with p.id in descending order.

Also, do you want to update the values for ones that are inserted only?

If updating from whole table, then you may use this.

```
ALTER TRIGGER trgAfterUpdate12 ON [spider3].[ProductClassModulePeriod]
FOR INSERT, UPDATE
AS
WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT  TOP 2 *
    FROM    [spider3].[ProductClassModulePeriod] p
    ORDER BY p.id DESC
)
UPDATE  cte
SET [lastUpdatedTime] = GETDATE()
```

Comment: Not only for inserted. But for the ones that are already there too

Comment: Okay, in that case, refer to new edit.

Comment: How can i use inner join with this?

Comment: Do you mean inner join with inserted? If so, I don't see use of it if you need to update last 2 row from main table.

Comment: I need last two rows the table with inner join. After tables are joined im getting more than 2 rows.

Comment: Yes inner join with inserted

Answer (score 0):

I have a question: Why it's TWO rows you want to update when the trigger works, I think the number of rows in the temp table "inserted" is unknown.
try if it works well:

```
UPDATE p 
SET [lastUpdatedTime] = GETDATE()
FROM [spider3].[ProductClassModulePeriod] AS p
INNER JOIN inserted AS i ON p.id = i.id;
```

Comment: When a change is done a new row is added with latest = 1 and the previous row is set to latest = 0. Only those two rows need to be updated. The other rows with latest = 0 do not need to be updated. Using your query all the rows are getting updated which is unnecessary.

Comment: latest = 0 or 1 means ?

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TRIGGER trgAfterUpdate ON [spider3].[ProductClassModulePeriod]
FOR INSERT, UPDATE
AS
WITH t AS
(
select TOP 1 p.id, p.lastUpdatedTime, p.primaryKey FROM [spider3].[ProductClassModulePeriod] AS p
INNER JOIN inserted AS i
ON p.id = i.id
order by p.primaryKey desc
)
UPDATE t
SET [lastUpdatedTime] = GETDATE();
```